# How to increase line width of svg image downloaded from the internet?

Tags: inkscape, logo, svg, line-art

I downloaded [this](https://svgsilh.com/image/148824.html) image with a creative commons license. I open it with inkscape, open the "Fill and Stroke" menu, use the cursor to select everything and then try to click on "width" under stroke style. However it always says 0 and if I press it it goes to 0.1 for a second before going back to 0.

How can I edit this image to have a bigger line thickness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not increase the stroke thickness because it's a shape with no strokes. Although at the beginning it was made with paths, now they are expanded and only have a black fill.

[image: shape]

The only way to increase the stroke is by adding one to the shapes, but you may not get the desired effect.

[image: Shape 2]

For such a simple shape, I would recommend using the SVG as a template and creating a new one.

[image: new shape]